# How upload photos to "Wall Photos"?

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

Normally i upload photos with this code:

```
$facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', array(
'source' => '@' . realpath(IMGDIR),
'message' => TEXT
)
```

If i upload photos with this code, photos are uploaded in "APPNAME Photos" but i'd want to upload photo in "Wall photos". How can i do this ? Sorry for my english!

Comment: be some more explanatory please?

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary I'd want to upload photos in the album: "Wall Photos".

Answer (score 0):

Can't you upload directly to the wall photos album?
e.g. With your code, changing `/me/photos` to `/<ALBUM ID>/photos` - that's how you'd do it for any generic album, I'm not sure if the wall photos album works like this

Make a GET request to /me/albums and get the user's list of albums, you should be able to upload to any of them

Comment: @lgy
Yes, your idea is ok!
  '$album = $facebook->api('/'PAGEID'/albums');
  foreach($album['data'] as $album){
  if($album['name'] == 'Wall Photos'){
           $album_post = $album['id'];
  }}
       $risultato['pagina'][$pagina['id']] = $facebook->api('/'.$album_post.'/photos', 'POST', array(
     'access_token'  => PAGETOKEN,
     'source' => '@' . IMAGE,
     'message' => TEXT
   )
);'
But i receive that error: Invalid album id thrown in base_facebook.php on line 1237

Answer (score 0):

You have to test

```
if($album['type'] == 'wall')
```